# How was this least squares polynomial obtained (solution provided)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Obtain a least squares polynomial of degree 2.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & \text{0} & \text{0.25} & \text{0.5}& \text{0.75}&\text{1} \\
\hline
y & 2.9646 & 3.1826 & 3.4773 & 4.1608 & 4.7182 \\
\end{array}
$$

$n=2,m=5$

$5a_0+2.5a_1+1.875a_2=18.6878$
$2.5a_0+1.875a_1+1.5625a_2=10.4062$
$1.875a_0+1.5625a_1+1.3828a_2=8.1147$

so $P_2(x)=2.9514+1.0968x+0.6340x^2$

I know how to get from the matrix to the polynomial equation, I am just not sure how to construct the system of equations. The notes are very hard to read and understand, it would be nice to get it in an easy to understand form, and then go back and consolidate what I have learned.

Answer (score 1):

We start with the sequence of measurements $\left\{ x_{k}, P_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$ and the trial function
$$
  P(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2} x^{2}.
$$
Use the method of least squares to find the best amplitudes $a$.

The linear system is 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} a &= b \\
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
     1  & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} \\
     1  & x_{2} & x_{2}^{2} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     1  & x_{m} & x_{m}^{2} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     a_{0} \\
     a_{1} \\
     a_{2} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     P(x_{0}) \\
     P(x_{1}) \\
     \vdots \\
     P(x_{m}) 
  \end{array}
\right].
\end{align}
$$

The least squares solution is the set of parameters $a$ which minimizes the sum of the squares of the residuals:
$$
\begin{align}
  r^{2}(a) &= 
\Bigg\lVert
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
     1  & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} \\
     1  & x_{2} & x_{2}^{2} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     1  & x_{m} & x_{m}^{2} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     a_{0} \\
     a_{1} \\
     a_{2} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
-
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     P(x_{1}) \\
     P(x_{2}) \\
     \vdots \\
     P(x_{m}) 
  \end{array}
\right]
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
& =
\sum_{k=1}^{m}
\left(
  P_{k} - P(x_{k})
\right)^{2}
=
\sum_{k=1}^{m}
\left(
  P_{k} - a_{0} - a_{1}x_{k} - a_{2}x_{k}^{2}
\right)^{2}
\end{align}
$$
The solution via pseudoinverse is $a=\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b$.

From your data,
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\frac{1}{16}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 16 & 0 & 0 \\
 16 & 4 & 1 \\
 16 & 8 & 4 \\
 16 & 12 & 9 \\
 16 & 16 & 16
\end{array}
\right], 
%
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{35}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
   31 &   9 &  -3 &  -5 &   3 \\
 -108 &  26 &  80 &  54 & -52 \\
   80 & -40 & -80 & -40 &  80
\end{array}
\right], 
%
b = 
\left[
\begin{array}{}
  2.9646 \\
  3.1826 \\
  3.4773 \\
  4.1608 \\
  4.7182
\end{array}
\right].
$$
The least squares solution vector is
$$
a = 
\left[
\begin{array}{}
  a_{0} \\
  a_{1} \\
  a_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
  2.95613 \\
  0.574046 \\
  1.22011
\end{array}
\right],
$$
with $r^{2}(a) = 0.0139$. The plot provides a qualitative view of the solution.

[image: The least squares solution for a quadratic polynomial plotted against the data points.]

Is your question about how to set up the normal equations? If you want to solve the problem using a process like Gaussian elimination, multiply both side of the equation by $\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}$:
$$
\mathbf{A}a = b \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{A}a = \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}b
$$
The solution is then
$$
 a = \left( \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}} y.
$$
The matrices of interest are
$$
\left( \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1} =
\frac{1} {35}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
   31 & -108 &   80 \\
 -108 &  696 & -640 \\
   80 & -640 &  640
\end{array}
\right],
\qquad
\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}b =
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
  18.5035 \\ 
  10.3731 \\
  8.12689
\end{array}
\right].
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the matrix product $X^t\times X$ with $X_{ik} = x_i^{k-1}$ and $i=1\dots5, k=1\dots 3$, cf. the Wiki article  [Polynomial_regression.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates)
With your values you have
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0\\
1 & 0.25 & 0.0625\\
1 & 0.5 & 0.25\\
1 & 0.75 & 0.5625\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that I cannot reproduce your RHS. I get 
$X^t \times y= (18.5035, 10.3731, 8.1268875),\,$ this near your RHS but obviously different.

Comment: How did you work out the last column of the matrix?

Comment: It contains the $x_i^2$